# How do I add missing rows (filled with 0's) in a data frame using some column as reference?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis, missing-data, data-cleaning

I have this (big) data frame and I want to add the missing rows (filled with 0's) in relation to the column named "date".

For example:

```
date    0        1         2          3         4         5
199807  0       546.98     19355.55   1110.6    4720.34   3435.9
199808  0       1668.85    4398.29    5816.71   599.7     535.28
199809  608.79  446.68     2297.68    1862.64   415.6     933.46
199811  0       0          1366.59    1337.01   0         711.59
199812  0       0          601.8      2079.9    2030.24   368.44
199901  0       1462.8     0          552.78    0         0
199903  0       621.2      2242       753.36    0         0
```

And I would like this:

```
date    0        1        2            3         4          5
199807  0        546.98   19355.55     1110.6    4720.34    3435.9
199808  0        1668.85  4398.29      5816.71   599.7      535.28
199809  608.79   446.68   2297.68      1862.64   415.6      933.46
199810  0        0        0            0         0          0
199811  0        0        1366.59      1337.01   0          711.59
199812  0        0        601.8        2079.9    2030.24    368.44
199901  0        1462.8   0            552.78    0          0
199902  0        0        0            0         0          0
199903  0        621.2    2242         753.36    0          0
```

Thank you very much

Comment: I think probably you have a row of zeros in the wrong place; should be the 199810 row? One way would be to `merge` with a data frame that contains all dates (although those aren't technically dates, but whatever) which will result in rows with `NA` and then replace the missing values with 0.

Comment: You are right. Thank you, I already edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done as follows:

1) Create a placeholder dataset with all dates and zeros in all other columns

2) for dates, which are in the original dataset, write values from original to placeholder dataset

```
# Create a placeholder dataset, including all dates, 0 at all other columns
df <- data.frame(date = c(199801:199812, 199901:199912),
                 `1` = 0, `2` = 0, `3` = 0, check.names = FALSE)

# create the dataset with some data (this will be the 'original' dataset)
df2 <- data.frame(date = c(199807:199809, 199811:199812, 199901:199903),
                  `1` = rnorm(8), `2` = rnorm(8), `3` = rnorm(8), check.names = FALSE)

# write data from original dataset to placeholder dataset
df[df$date %in% df2$date,] <- df2
```